# FinalBuilder History Log Columns

Tags: history, finalbuilder

We are using FinalBuilder 7.

When we do builds using FinalBuilder, we have a BuildConfig parameter that determines if we are building to Testing, Staging or Release.

Last when looking through the history log, if you want to know what server was targeted, you have to click into each history item and then expand the build parameters in order to see the BuildConfig value.

I would like to know if there is a way to customize the main Project History list to include information from the build like the BuildConfig value???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Log Variable Values action to write the value to the log. As for auto expanding, not possible, however you can search for them. You can change the title of the action so it's easy to find in the log.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I guess I wasn't totally clear about what I meant by History Log. I am not talking about the individual logs. I am talking about the Project History list. It is the list that shows each build with a date and time. This way I could look through it and quickly know which build I am looking for based on the BuildConfig. Can I add columns to that list?

Comment: No, sorry, not possible at this time.